# Unable to find reason eventually building flutter project working fine few minutes earlier

Tags: flutter

[debug screen shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfiFT.png)

- Working on flutter 3.3.0 for a project.
- Few minutes earlier able to build project successfully, eventually it throws an error.
- last thing added in the project is shared preferences with :any suffic in pubspec.xml

Comment: have you tried `flutter clean` and run the app again?

Comment: Yes @SujanGainju i tried all such things that rebuilds project and create folder build but it got resolved as it was Android Studio environments settings that got edited by some terminal commands which worked on restoring the Android Studio Setting to the factory default. Thanks for your attempt in answering the question, keep spreading the solution in your developer groups in need.